# How do I have a personal project in JavaScript and use `import`?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a personal project in JavaScript.

So I started with an empty folder with two files:

```
card.js
constants.js
```

and in `card.js`, I used on the first line:

```
import { SUIT } from "./constants.js";
```

and run it using `node card.js`. It doesn't work, giving the error:

> (node:91577) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.

First,

> set "type": "module" in the package.json

I don't even have a package.json. Must I use it? Can I not use one? If I set "type": "module", does that make my own project become a module?

Second, I have never seen any `.mjs` file ever before.  What is it about?  I can use that and forget everything about NodeJS or package.json?

If I look at the [docs for import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), it has:

```
import { myExport } from "/modules/my-module.js";
```

So I used `mkdir modules` and moved that `constants.js` in there.
And then I used:

```
import { SUIT } from "/modules/constants.js"
```

and it still has the same error. That doc doesn't not mention `package.json` whatsoever.

I am wondering if this `import` is the same as `import` in the context of NodeJS (and so it may be different in Deno).

How is it done?

**P.S.** I renamed `constants.js` to `constants.mjs` and got the same error.

**P.P.S.** I can use `npm init` to init the project and create a package.json file, except it looks like that will make my project become an npm package. But my project is meant to be an app, not a package.

I then, after getting stuck for 30 minutes and getting bashed by nice fellow programmers, tried for:

> use the .mjs extension

and not just used `constants.mjs`, but also, used `card.mjs`, and `node cards.mjs` and it runs. I also need to use `import { SUIT } from "./constants.mjs";` Anyways, the statement "use the .mjs extension" is not so clear as to "use it where?"

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257305/discussion-on-question-by-stefanie-gauss-how-do-i-have-a-personal-project-in-jav); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.